When can the complete solution of a linear differential equation using Green's function be represented using convolution?
I have come across at least one literature source and the Wikipedia webpage of Green's function where it is mentioned that the solution of a linear ODE or a PDE using Green's function is the convolution of the Green's function with the source term. Is this always true or is it case specific ?
For example, consider the linear ODE $L u = \phi$  which governs the solution $u(x)$ when subjected to source term $\phi(x)$. If $G(\xi,x)$ represents the Green's function of the ODE(with $\xi$ as the running variable) then the complete solution of $u(x)$ is
$$ u(x) =  \int_{a}^{b} G(\xi,x) \phi(\xi) d \xi$$.
In the literature source, where the pressure wave equation is subjected to a time-harmonic(sine term) point source, the solution is written as
$$ p(x,y,t) = \phi * G$$.
My question is, under what scenarios can the complete solution using the Green's function be represented using this kind of convolution operation ? I have referred to a bunch of textbooks but the usage of convolution is not mentioned beyond the application of Laplace transforms.
